# Options menu shows up but is empty

Tags: android, android-menu

As my first post here, I will try to be as precise as possible.

**Summary:**
I can't make a working `options menu`. When the *Menu* button is pressed, an empty black menu shows up. There is the right amount of items (you can "see" the button being pressed) but their `android:title` are ignored, the `onCreateOptionsMenu` triggers a warning and `onOptionsItemSelected` is always zero. See screenshots and outputs for details.

**My environment:**
My development environment is Debian Jessie 64bits. It runs in a VM.
*android-sdk* is up to date. *android-ndk* is 11b.
In order to investigate on a clean base, I set up a new "Hello World" project:

```
$ SDK=/path/to/android-sdk-linux/
$ $SDK/tools/android create project --target android-16 --path ~/projects/test --package com.arnaud.test --activity Test
```

**The code:**
It's basically an "Hello World" with 2 diffs:

*res/menu/menu.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://shemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item   android:id="@+id/menuFoo"
        android:title="Foo"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item   android:id="@+id/menuBar"
        android:title="Bar"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
    <item   android:id="@+id/menuBaz"
        android:title="Baz"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

*src/com/arnaud/src/Test.java*

```
package com.arnaud.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Test extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    /** Build the menu*/
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);

        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) {
        Log.w("Menu","Id clicked: "+item.getItemId());
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuFoo:
            Log.w("Menu","Foo");
            return true;
        case R.id.menuBar:
            Log.w("Menu","Bar");
            return true;
        case R.id.menuBaz:
            Log.w("Menu","Baz");
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    }
}
```

**The output**
is identical on Kitkat and Marshmallow. Here are 3 screenshots and the logcat output.
[menu shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtcvb.png) and [an item is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnjjO.png)

```
    -- Here I click on the menu button --
    05-04 16:02:37.719  1701  1701 D EmojiAltPhysicalKeyDetector: onKeyUp() : KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_MENU, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=3226804, downTime=3226804, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }
    05-04 16:02:37.719  1701  1701 D EmojiAltPhysicalKeyDetector: onKeyUp() : Disabled
    05-04 16:02:37.727   933  1205 D AudioService: Stream muted, skip playback

    -- Here I blindly selected one of the three items --
    05-04 16:02:42.023  3663  3663 W Menu: Id clicked:   0  -- No item is passed apparently.
    05-04 16:02:42.032   933  1973 W InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@6c70840 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@93c26bc -- The warning.
```

So this is it. I have been wondering if the lack of `styles.xml` was the problem but that doesn't explain why the items are not responding.

Comment: Can you post your styles. There's a good chance you set a style that causing your text to be white.
And have you tried  onPrepareOptionsMenu()?
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: you want the menu items at the top of the app, right? but you dont have ActionBar of Toolbar?

Comment: You should set a theme in your `styles.xml` and see what happens.

Comment: Setting and using a styles.xml made the app crash depending on the theme used. I prefered leaving the app decide. I built the menu through onPrepareOptionsMenu() and it worked. That is my workaround for now but that still doesn't explain why menu.xml fail.